# echoing out @ symbol when pulling emails from mysql database in WP page

Tags: mysql, wordpress, special-characters

Here is the code I'm using that is pulling all data fields nicely from mysql database. But email addresses are being displayed as `user%40domainname.com` instead of standard email output of `user@domainname.com`.

```
$myData = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table class='table table-hover table-bordered table-striped'>
          <tr>
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Score</th>
          </tr>";

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['score'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Is it "%40" not just %? Maybe things are being encoded.

Comment: yes you are right, its %40

Comment: That means you mistakenly called `urlencode()` when you were storing the data in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urldecode.php) to solve this:

```
$email = 'user%40domainname.com';
echo urldecode($email); //user@domainname.com
```

> **demo:** http://ideone.com/hEdpxk

... or in your case you can use the following `while` loop:

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . urldecode($record['email']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['score'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help